# ClassNotFoundException when connecting from Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, google-cloud-sql, gcp-databricks

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when I try connecting from Databricks on GCP:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1808.jdbc.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2466)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:672)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2747)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:400)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:400)
<<snip>>
```

I'm using a Python notebook to connect:

```py
password = "..."
connection_name = "...:...:..."  # copied from console

display(
    spark.read.jdbc(f"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=avoidable_events;socketFactoryClass=com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory;user=sqlserver;socketFactoryConstructorArg={connection_name};password={password}", table="thedb.thetable")
)
```

Cluster is `9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)`

Libraries installed:

- `com.google.cloud.sql:cloud-sql-connector-jdbc-sqlserver:1.6.1` via Maven
- `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:10.2.0.jre8` via Maven

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the maintainers of github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory, and your connection string looks right, from what you've shared. I admittedly don't know a lot about Databricks, but would you mind walking me through how you installed the libraries via Maven? Did you follow these steps? https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/28/using-3rd-party-libraries-in-databricks-apache-spark-packages-and-maven-libraries.html

Comment: yes, this %scala code returns the right class: `Class.forName("com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory")`

Comment: Have you tried an older version of cloud-sql-connector-jdbc-sqlserver? Have you tried connecting to a Cloud SQL Postgres or MySQL instance?